# Android Nexus 7 Enable GPS Sensor

Tags: html, gps

I'm just starting to play with some app development using HTML5 and Phonegap.  I'm trying to use the GPS - with Wifi disabled - to display lon/lat coordinates.  The code works... sort of.

If I open the app, I don't get the location.  If I open any other app that uses geolocation - Google maps or a GPS tester - and then switch back to my app, it works and updates the coordinates.  It's like my app isn't switching the GPS sensor on but once it IS switched on, my app has access to it.

Am I missing something?

Code;

```
<script>
  window.onload = function() {
    var startPos;

    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        enableHighAccuracy: true;
        startPos = position;
        document.getElementById("startLat").innerHTML = startPos.coords.latitude;
        document.getElementById("startLon").innerHTML = startPos.coords.longitude;
      }, function(error) {
        alert("Error occurred. Error code: " + error.code);
        // error.code can be:
        //   0: unknown error
        //   1: permission denied
        //   2: position unavailable (error response from locaton provider)
        //   3: timed out
      });

      navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(function(position) {
        enableHighAccuracy: true;
        document.getElementById("currentLat").innerHTML = position.coords.latitude;
        document.getElementById("currentLon").innerHTML = position.coords.longitude;
        document.getElementById("distance").innerHTML =
          calculateDistance(startPos.coords.latitude, startPos.coords.longitude,
                            position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
      });
    }
  };

  // Reused code - copyright Moveable Type Scripts - retrieved May 4, 2010.
  // http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html
  // Under Creative Commons License http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/
  function calculateDistance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) {
    var R = 6371; // km
    var dLat = (lat2-51.202399).toRad();
    var dLon = (lon2-parseFloat(-1.479645)).toRad();
    var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
            Math.cos(51.202399.toRad()) * Math.cos(lat2.toRad()) *
            Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2);
    var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
    var d = R * c;
    return d.toFixed(2);
  }
  Number.prototype.toRad = function() {
    return this * Math.PI / 180;
  }
</script>
```

Best regards
Andy

Answer (score 0):

Use org.apache.cordova.geolocation plugin.

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation

Comment: Thanks for that!  Forgive my ignorance but this is very new to me. I'm just using Dreamweaver to edit my code.  I then just zip it up, upload to build.phonegap.com and install the app on my device.

I don't understand how this plugin fits, or where?

Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Ah, you use PhoneGap Build. Ok, read this page http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_plugins.md.html#Plugins and https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/1176